# Interleaved VBO causing glDrawArrays() error

Tags: objective-c, ios, opengl-es, rendering, vbo

I recently changed my app from using OpenGL ES 1.1 to 2.0, and in the process I decided to optimise my code further by using VBOs. I think I've got to grips with the main differences with ES 2.0, and have results to show that I'm doing things correctly without VBOs, however I've been stumped by a problem that only presents itself when I try to use VBOs.

I use a custom struct containing vertex position, color and size (plus a little padding to align data), and then interleave this vertex data in a VBO. This data is used to render point sprites. The problem is that I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS on the glDrawArrays() call. The backtrace at this error is as follows:

```
#0  0x31fc7358 in gleRunVertexSubmitARM ()
#1  0x31fc87b2 in gleLLVMArrayFunc ()
#2  0x31fc872a in gleSetVertexArrayFunc ()
#3  0x31fbefcc in gleDrawArraysOrElements_ExecCore ()
#4  0x31fc4608 in glDrawArrays_IMM_Exec ()
#5  0x36ddaee2 in glDrawArrays ()
#6  0x0001cab8 in -[Renderer renderDrawingVertexBuffer:withSize:usingTexture:] (self=0x1783b0, _cmd=0x50fec, vboID=0, size=3584, drawTexture=5) at /Users/Stu/Documents/...
#7  0x000202f4 in -[EAGLView drawSmoothCurveFromPoints:endOfLine:] (self=0x195be0, _cmd=0x50d34, points=0x1956f0, endOfLine=1 '\001') at /Users/Stu/Documents/...
#8  0x0001e50c in -[EAGLView drawView:] (self=0x195be0, _cmd=0x50d8a, sender=0x0) at /Users/Stu/Documents/...
#9  0x0001e174 in -[EAGLView layoutSubviews] (self=0x195be0, _cmd=0x3297d4ac) at /Users/Stu/Documents/...
#10 0x326805fa in -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] ()
#11 0x35efbf02 in -[NSObject(NSObject) performSelector:withObject:] ()
#12 0x333fbbb4 in -[CALayer layoutSublayers] ()
#13 0x333fb96c in CALayerLayoutIfNeeded ()
```

This is the struct for storing vertex data:

```
typedef struct {
    ISVertex2D vertex;     // Made up of 2 GLfloats.
    ISColor    color;      // Made up of 4 GLfloats.
    GLfloat    size;
    GLfloat    padding;
} ISPointSpriteData;
```

After a set of data is stored in an array of these structs, the data is sent to the VBO and rendered using glDrawArrays():

```
[renderer prepareScene];
[renderer renderBackground];

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, penVbo);
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(ISPointSpriteData) * penVboSize, sizeof(ISPointSpriteData) * vertexCount, &vertexBuffer[0].vertex);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, drawTexture);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_VERTEX);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_COLOR);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_SIZE);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_TEXTURE_COORD);
glUniform1i(uniforms[UNIFORM_IS_SPRITE], GL_TRUE);

glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_VERTEX, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(ISPointSpriteData), (void*)offsetof(ISPointSpriteData, vertex));
glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_COLOR, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(ISPointSpriteData), (void*)offsetof(ISPointSpriteData, color));
glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_SIZE, 1, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(ISPointSpriteData), (void*)offsetof(ISPointSpriteData, size));

glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, vertexCount);     // <--- EXC_BAD_ACCESS

glDisableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_VERTEX);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_COLOR);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_SIZE);


[renderer presentScene];
```

This code worked right before I put the VBO in, with the only alteration being that the last parameter of the glVertexAttribPointer() calls would obviously point to the data rather than an offset. What am I missing? I don't think this code is particularly complicated so I can only think that I've made a stupid mistake somewhere.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Problem solved:**

There were a few things wrong with my code, not all of which would have been apparent from the listings in the question. I'll outline the major issues:

- In code not listed, I was creating
  the VBOs in a utility function. In
  this function I was incorrectly
  passing the `GLuint` handle for the
  buffer (I was attempting to pass it
  by reference in a function that
  returns void). In the interests of
  making this more readable I changed
  the function to simply initialise its
  own handle and return it. This
  stopped the program crashing at the
  `glDrawArrays()` line (presumably the
  uninitialised value must already have
  been assigned to another buffer
  somewhere).

A new problem presented itself - the screen was being drawn to black and there were BIG delays between draw calls. This was caused by...

- Not unbinding the VBOs after
  each draw call. For each frame a
  background texture is first drawn,
  followed by the contents of the VBOs.
  By leaving the VBOs bound for the
  next background render, I was
  obviously causing OGL to have a bit
  of a fit! This was not only the cause
  of the black screen, but also the big
  delays between draw calls.

Hope this is helpful to somebody else in a similar situation!

Answer (score 0):

You might have to use glDrawElements instead of glDrawArrays. Because glDrawArrays does not allow hopping or skipping. It reads from a contiguous set of vertices.

"glDrawArrays() reads vertex data from the enabled arrays by marching straight through the array without skipping or hopping. Because glDrawArrays() does not allows hopping around the vertex arrays, you still have to repeat the shared vertices once per face."

http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_vertexarray.html

Comment: I don't need to hop or skip in the data. I'm rendering point sprites and so all I need is for glDrawArrays() to plough through my contiguous vertex data.

Comment: What's more, I should add that I successfully adapted Apple's GLES2Sample sample app to use a VBO in much the same fashion as I am trying to here.

Comment: I believe you have the vertex data in the structure format. Which means the vertex data is not present contiguously in the memory. Each vertex data is present with a sizeof(ISPointSpriteData) gap. Did you try out glDrawElements?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean, sorry. The data is interleaved, and all the data in the struct is used in the shaders. So there is a gap of sizeof(ISPointSpriteData) between the start of each set of vertex data, but all the data in between is required and read by glDrawArrays() I thought. Sorry, I'm not great with the really low level understanding of memory. Incidentally, I did try out glDrawElements, and it did not affect my problem.

Comment: I have been playing around with things a lot today, and I solved the problem. Amongst other things, I was not unbinding the VBOs after the draw call. I have posted a complete explanation in a separate answer. Thanks very much for the help though.